# user and group ids scrambled when using NFS

Tags: linux, user-accounts, nfs

I'm using nfs to mount the folder `/mirror` from a server onto a node.

This works, except on the node the user and group are displayed as "4294967294".

On the server:   `ls -al ./ displays`

```
-rw-r--r--  1 cu cu    0 2011-07-11 15:08 test1
-rw-r--r--  1 cu cu    0 2011-07-11 15:08 test2
```

whereas on the node

```
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294    0 2011-07-11 15:08 test1
-rw-r--r--  1 4294967294 4294967294    0 2011-07-11 15:08 test2
```

I have `usermod` and `groupmod` the username `cu` to have the same numbers on the node.

On the server: `id` displays

```
uid=1021(cu) gid=1007(cu) groups=1007(cu),109(admin)
```

on the node

```
uid=1021(cu) gid=1007(cu) groups=1007(cu)
```

I'm stumpeed as to what the problem could be.

I should perhaps add that the home directory is `/mirror/cu` (so that the users share the same account when mounted).  Not sure if thats relevent though...

My `/etc/exports` file (on the server) looks like this

```
/mirror *(rw,sync)
```

and I do the mount (on the node) with

```
sudo mount server:/mirror /mirror
```

Comment: I would flag this as a duplicate of 
http://serverfault.com/questions/98741/files-mounted-over-nfsv4-are-owned-by-4294967294-uids-and-gids-match but seen as its on another site I can't... hmm...

Comment: Yes, didn't see that one (didn't google the actual number - I thought it was a random number!) Thanks

Comment: Apparently its an overflow of -2. There's no accepted answer in that link but at least lots of options. Common amongst google seems the idea that its an imapd problem, but also that its several problems in one. Before you do anything else I'd suggest a reboot (or restart of the involved services) 'just incase' some config somewhere hasn't been taken up :-P

Comment: Thanks @PriceChild: this answer worked for me: http://serverfault.com/questions/98741/files-mounted-over-nfsv4-are-owned-by-4294967294-uids-and-gids-match/236398#236398

Comment: Aha which then links to http://serverfault.com/questions/223408/uid-gid-with-nfs-and-zfs#answer-223415 ! Awesome. Meh as I'm not sure this question can be marked as a duplicate, post the result in an 'answer' and accept it yourself tomorrow :-)

Comment: do as @PriceChild mentions

Comment: To clarify... by 'tomorrow', i meant post it yourself as an answer asap (you can't accept your own answer until ~24h have passed)

Comment: @PrinceChild, sorry for the delay - I was going to try and get to the bottom of the problem before posting an answer, but then something came up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @PriceChild notes, this question is a [duplicate](https://serverfault.com/questions/98741/files-mounted-over-nfsv4-are-owned-by-4294967294-uids-and-gids-match).

However, no answers were accepted to that question.  I tried this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/98741/files-mounted-over-nfsv4-are-owned-by-4294967294-uids-and-gids-match/236398#236398) first, namely
 adding

```
-o vers=3
```

to the mount command, and that worked for me.

The rationale for this (using version 3 of NFS rather than version 4) is [that](https://serverfault.com/questions/223408/uid-gid-with-nfs-and-zfs/223415#223415)

> NFSv4 doesn't use UID/GIDs anymore. There are quite a few significant
>   differences between NFSv3 and v4; security is one of them.

**Note:** I was satisfied with this fix and I didn't get to the root of the problem.  If you want to take if further, the aforementioned links should help.